# Swift - Get value of textField form with Eureka

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I am doing an app with Eureka form, and the problem is that I don't know how to get the value of the first textField.

The problem is that I should get the value of the first section DecimalRow and I should multiply it with the textField of the second section KalkulationCell (that is a custom cell) and I don't know how to merge these parts.

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

class ViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //var rules = RuleSet<String>()

        form +++ Section("EINGABESUMME BRUTTO (EXXL MWST)")

        {$0.header?.height = { 20 }}
            <<< DecimalRow(){
                $0.title = " "
              //$0.value = 54
                $0.tag = "MyRowTag"

        }

            .cellUpdate { cell, row in
                    cell.textField?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)

        }



        let row: DecimalRow? = form.rowBy(tag: "MyRowTag")
        let value = row?.value

        // Get the value of all rows which have a Tag assigned
        // The dictionary contains the 'rowTag':value pairs.
        let valuesDictionary = form.values()
        print(valuesDictionary)




        form +++ Section("ZIEL-DB PROJEKT BRUTTO")
        {
            $0.header?.height = { 20 }

            }

            <<< KalkulationRow {
              row in
       row.cell.valueField.text = "54.00"

                row.tag="hello"
         }




        form +++ Section("RABATT")
        {
            $0.header?.height = { 20 }

            }
            <<< KalkulationRow { row in
                 row.cell.valueField.text = "54.00"

        }


        form +++ Section("SKONTO")
        {
            $0.header?.height = { 20 }

            }

            <<< IntRow(){
                $0.title = "Tage:"
                $0.placeholder = "2"
                $0.add(rule: RuleRequired())

                }
                .cellUpdate { cell, row in

                    cell.textField?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
            }
            <<< KalkulationRow { row in
                 row.cell.valueField.text = "54.00"
        }
        form +++ Section("DIVERSE ABZUGE")
        {
            $0.header?.height = { 20 }

            }
            <<< KalkulationRow { row in
                row.cell.valueField.text = "54.00"
        }



        form +++ Section("EINGABESSUME NETTO")
        {
            $0.header?.height = { 20 }

            }
            <<< DecimalRow(){
                $0.title = " "
                $0.value = 54.00
                $0.placeholderColor = UIColor.green


                }
                .cellUpdate { cell, row in
                    cell.textField?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
                    cell.textField?.textColor = UIColor.green
                    cell.textField?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }


        form +++ Section("ZIEL-DB PROJEKT NETTO")
        {
            $0.header?.height = { 20 }

            }

            <<< KalkulationRow { row in
                 row.cell.valueField.text = "54.00"
        }


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please make your question more specific? Which section of your code is related to this issue?

Comment: Thanks. In the View Controller  in the first section  Decimal Row i want to print  that value that is written

Comment: OK. If you could post your code that would help very much. Click the "Edit" link under your question, copy/paste the relevant code, and indent it four spaces to create a code block.

Comment: These other Stack Overflow questions may also help you: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716588/swift-how-to-get-form-values-using-eureka-form-builder (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951503/get-values-from-eureka-forms-in-swift (3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47106487/eureka-forms-getting-form-values

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka). There is a lot of sample code.

Comment: thanks  @vadian I've read it but doesnt have exactly what i am looking, also doesn't have any tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vadian suggested You can detect text change with `onChange` method as shown below:

```
.onChange({ decimal in

     print(decimal)
})
```

And final code will be:

```
{
        $0.header?.height = { 20 }

        }
        <<< DecimalRow(){
            $0.title = " "
            $0.tag = "MyRowTag"

            }
            .onChange({ decimal in

                print(decimal)
            })
            .cellUpdate { cell, row in
                cell.textField?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
}
```

Comment: No need to do that, all Eureka rows have closures which are called *onChange*.

Comment: Thanks @vadian adding same in answer.